# data Importer for excel files but data types are conflicting

Tags: mysql, sql-server, vb.net, excel

I'm creating a sql-database-table dynamically via vb.net and dynamic-SQL

the table I'm creating's column names are retrieved via a oledb-ace connection and a my-sql statement to retrieve the data. but my dataset returns most of the column names i need just not the column names that have a series of Numerical values underneath it.

I'm using the first row to determine the values to use for the table columns in sql. 
the problem seems to be that the columns underneath these blank fields are supposed to be int in sql and something must be converting the first value row values in the excel sheets I'm using to "number" or "int" is there anyway that i can return the first row like this

```
"SELECT Top 1  * FROM [" & ExcelSHEET & "]"
```

but then Cast or force it to be `Text` or `varchar` ??

All i need is a list of string values the same as that of the first row in the excel sheet

thanks :)

Comment: Syntax in your example is for MS SQL server, not MySQL. Are you using both?

Comment: yes using my-sql to query from excel , and actual sql to create table in sql-server

Comment: but how is this not coherent with "my-sql" syntax ?

Comment: MySQL doesn't support `SELECT TOP` while MSSQL server does. MySQL should use `... LIMIT 1` instead.

Comment: lol all good , the select Top 1  * FROM , still works ... i just added imex to the end of my connection string . there are realy cool extended properties( Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml; HDR=NO; imex=1"") soo the problem has been solved